# How can this code be changed to turn an integer to a nine digit binary string?

Tags: python

I found this code and it works for part of what I need it to do, but I do not understand how it works. Can someone first explain how it works?

And then I need the binary strings that are fewer than 9 digits to fill in with 0's before the binary. For example, the binary for 50 is 110010, but I need it to be represented as: 000110010.

```
decimal = eval(input("Enter an integer between 0 and 511: "))

binaryString = ""
value = decimal

while value != 0:
    binaryString = str(value % 2) + binaryString
    value = value // 2

print(str(decimal) + "'s binary representation is " + binaryString)
```

Comment: Never use `eval(input(...))`; you may be *expecting* input like `123`, but the user can just as easily type an arbitrary Python expression that will be evaluated.

Comment: you can add more zeros with `binaryString.zfill(9)`

Comment: Use `int(input())` in a try-except block instead of `eval(input())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current method works by producing the binary digits from the "bottom up". In each iteration, a new digit is prepended to the preceding number.

For example, let's say the number to be encoded is 159.

At the first iteration, `binaryString` is set to `1` (because `str(159 % 2) == '1'`). Then 159 is halved. Integer division `159 // 2` results in truncation to 79.

In the second iteration, the next digit is again a `'1'` (because `str(79 % 2) == '1'`). That is prepended to the preceding digit, giving `'11'`.  The value is again halved, resulting in (79 // 2) => 39

And so forth. Then:

```
(39 % 2) == 1     =>   '111'           39 // 2 => 19
(19 % 2) == 1     =>   '1111'          19 // 2 => 9
(9 % 2) == 1      =>   '11111'          9 // 2 => 4
(4 % 2) == 0      =>   '011111'         4 // 2 => 2
(2 % 2) == 0      =>   '0011111'        2 // 2 => 1
(1 % 2) == 1      =>   '10011111'       1 // 0 => 0
STOP
```

Here the algorithm stops because the result became zero. If you use this method, therefore, you'll need to pad at the beginning with additional zeroes until you have 9 digits. However, instead of

```
while value != 0:
```

You could instead use this as a loop control with the same inner contents:

```
for bit_no in range(9):
```

Then the loop will simply run 9 times, producing exactly 9 binary digits (it just produces additional zero digits once your `value` has gone to zero).